# Convert a xamarin.forms.view to an uiview ...?

Tags: view, uiview, xamarin.ios, converters

I work on a xamarin.iOS project and I need to convert a Xamarin.Forms.View to an UIView. I managed to do what I want on Android, but not on iOS.
I have tried to use this method found [here](http://www.michaelridland.com/xamarin/creating-native-view-xamarin-forms-viewpage/):

```
public static UIView ConvertFormsToNative(Xamarin.Forms.View view, CGRect size)
{
    var renderer = RendererFactory.GetRenderer (view); 
    renderer.NativeView.Frame = size; 
    renderer.NativeView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
    renderer.NativeView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill; 
    renderer.Element.Layout (size.ToRectangle()); 
    var nativeView = renderer.NativeView; 
    nativeView.SetNeedsLayout ();
    return nativeView;
}
```

But it's not work in my project ...

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: "it's not work" is not very precise... Could you please describe what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget using `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` in the appdelegate.

I tried with a Xamarin map control but it does not work. I use this and voila!

```
public partial class ViewControllerCliente : UIViewController........


var map = new Map(

MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(

new Position(37, -122), Distance.FromMiles(0.3)))
{

  IsShowingUser = true,

  HeightRequest = 200,

  WidthRequest = 200,

VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand

};


var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };

stack.Children.Add(map);


this.Add(ConvertFormsToNative(stack,new CGRect(0, 180, 

UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width,360)));
```